# Efficient parallel union of sets with OpenMP

Tags: c++, stl, openmp

I need to calculate a global `std::set` (or equivalently a global `std::unordered_set`) in an OpenMP parallelised programm. At the moment every thread has a local `std::set` which then later the union is calculated from using

```
#pragma omp critical //critical as std container inserting is not thread safe 
global_set.insert(local_set.begin(), local_set.end());
```

However this creates an effectively serial section of code, where each thread inserts its local set into the global set one after the other.

**How can I improve on this by parallelising the union of the sets?** The union is preceded by a large block of work, is there a convenient way to give all threads different amounts of work to let the others work while one is inserting the elements in the set? Or can the union itself be efficiently parallelised (for example by unioning sets in a 'binary tree' fashion)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read up on [OpenMP reductions](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu107.html#x140-5800002.19.5), and, in particular user-defined reductions. That lets you pass the problem to the OpenMP implementation, which will very likely perform the reduction up a tree.

Of course, whether that is beneficial is not clear; it may be that it simply introduces a lot of copying and memory allocation which is still slower than the style of code you show.

Comment: [Here](https://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#TheReductionClause_2) is a good explanation for OpenMP reduction

Comment: I accepted this because it was very helpful and indeed solves the problem of unioning the sets in a binary tree fashion. However for people finding this question: 'binary tree union' is probably not a good way to do this, as the size of the set roughly doubles on each reduction step and the complexity of unioning is linear in the number of elements, doing it in a binary tree fashion is not better complexity wise. I ended up using a lock free global data set (alternatively a bloom filter with a custom reduction); while this is specific to my use case, it might help as an idea.